How does Christianity know Jesus?
Matt 11-27 states no one knows the son but the father. In my life I've been asked several times do you know Jesus? Or would you like to know Jesus?  So I read scripture and am wondering how Christianity knows him . he's painted different in the bible than our reality or maybe just mine. Matthew 10-34-39 the answer is in revelations.the Jesus in this world does not match scripture but one way?

Welcome to the Biblical Hermeneutics SE John. We are glad you are here. Please take a moment to take the site tour and check out educating new users and the FAQs. Could you please clarify what specific aspects of Jesus’ portrayal in scripture and reality you find conflicting? This will help us provide a more focused and helpful response.

If the question is asking how do Christians know Jesus, then Jesus himself gives the answer. The reference to Matthew 11:27 starts the answer, but the entire verse needs to be grasped, not just the 8 words given in the question. The whole sentence reads:

"All things are delivered unto me of my Father: and no man knoweth the
Son, but the Father; neither knoweth any man the Father, save the Son,
and he to whomsoever the Son will reveal him." Matthew 11:27 K.J.V.

The Father and the Son are so bound up together, people need the Son to reveal the Father to them. Equally, Jesus said in chapter 16 verses 15-17 that the Father had revealed to the Apostle Peter just who Jesus (the Son) truly is - the Son of God. Upon that heavenly insight and declaration of faith in Jesus, Peter came to know Jesus in the only way that makes a person a Christian - by revelation from above. To those who come to know Christ that way, Jesus said that if they had seen him, they had seen the Father (John 14:6-11). Not literally, of course. Jesus came to reveal the Father to repentant sinners. Believing his words in the Bible, seeing how he lived, and following him ties in with the other Matthew verses alluded to in the question. Here is how the Apostle John put it:

"He that loveth his life shall lose it; and he that hateth his life in
this world shall keep it unto life eternal. If any man serve me, let
him follow me: and where I am, there shall also my servant be; if any
man serve me, him will my Father honour." John 12:25-26 K.J.V.

Those who know Christ are the Christians who love him more than their own lives, putting him first in their lives, living to honour Christ by serving him. Such servants of Christ have Christ present with them. That's how you can tell the difference between those with the spirit of Christ in them, and those who only have a head-knowledge about Christ.
Finally, it is certainly true that Jesus is unique, and only by taking the whole Bible into account and having the spirit of Christ open our spiritual eyes and ears can we begin to understand the immensity of just who the Son of God is. This is the work of the Holy Spirit. Thus, Father, Son and Holy Spirit lead a person to turn in faith the Jesus Christ. Those so led are Christians, and that is how they come to know Jesus: the start of a life-time of learning and serving.

Christianity cannot know anything.  However a Christian can know the Son and the Father and the Spirit of God:
[1Jo 5:20 KJV] And we know that the Son of God is come, and hath given us an understanding, that we may know him that is true, and we are in him that is true, [even] in his Son Jesus Christ. This is the true God, and eternal life.
[Jhn 17:3 KJV] And this is life eternal, that they might know thee the only true God, and Jesus Christ, whom thou hast sent.
[1Jo 4:2 KJV] Hereby know ye the Spirit of God: Every spirit that confesseth that Jesus Christ is come in the flesh is of God:
The key for you to know Jesus is found here: [Jhn 5:24 ESV] Truly, truly, I say to you, whoever hears my word and believes him who sent me has eternal life. He does not come into judgment, but has passed from death to life.
